# Contents from spreadsheet are not uploading into .html

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

So I have an google appscript code that looks like this.
It's basically taking the contents from a selected row in spreadsheet, puts them in the correct parts of the email2.html that is autogenerated and sent.
I also have an attachment.html file that's supposed to work just the same way - some of the data should be filled from the spreadsheet and then attached to the email, but no matter what I do - it doesn't work.

Here's the full code:

Code.gs:

```js
   

function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TransportPlan");

  // Get attachment.html content
  var attachmentContent = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('attachment.html').getContent();
  var attachmentBlob = Utilities.newBlob(attachmentContent, 'text/html', 'attachment.html');

  // Display UI prompt for row number selection
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Enter row number', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Exit function if user clicks "Cancel"
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    return;
  }

  // Retrieve row number entered by user
  var rowNumber = parseInt(response.getResponseText());

  // Retrieve data from spreadsheet for selected row
  var range = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = range.getValues()[0];
  var dateG = range.getCell(1, 7).getValue();

  var timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var formattedDateG = Utilities.formatDate(dateG, timeZone, 'dd-MM-yyyy');

  var timeM = range.getCell(1, 13).getValue();
  var formattedTimeM = Utilities.formatDate(timeM, timeZone, 'HH:mm');

  var timeN = range.getCell(1, 14).getValue();
  var formattedTimeN = Utilities.formatDate(timeN, timeZone, 'HH:mm');

  // Create email subject
  var emailSubject = "Transport Plan: " + data[3] + " | " + data[8] + " ➦ " + data[10];

  // Create email body from HTML template and replace placeholders with data
  var emailTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("EMAIL2");

  // Map the data array to column letters and set it in the email template
  const columnLetters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BK'];
  data.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (index == 6) {
      emailTemplate[columnLetters[index]] = formattedDateG;
    } else if (index == 12) {
      emailTemplate[columnLetters[index]] = formattedTimeM;
    } else if (index == 13) {
      emailTemplate[columnLetters[index]] = formattedTimeN;
    } else {
      emailTemplate[columnLetters[index]] = value;
    }
  });

  var emailBody = emailTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

  // Get email addresses from the "EmailAdress" sheet for the selected row
    var emailAddressesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EmailAdress");
  var emailAddressesRange = emailAddressesSheet.getDataRange();
  var emailAddressesData = emailAddressesRange.getValues();
  var selectedRowId = data[9];

  // Find the row in the "EmailAdress" sheet with the corresponding ID
  var emailAddresses = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < emailAddressesData.length; i++) {
    if (emailAddressesData[i][0] == selectedRowId) {
      // Add all email addresses for the selected row to the emailAddresses array
      for (var j = 2; j < emailAddressesData[i].length; j++) {
        if (emailAddressesData[i][j]) {
          emailAddresses.push(emailAddressesData[i][j]);
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  // Send email to all email addresses for the selected row
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddresses.join(),
    subject: emailSubject,
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    attachments: [attachmentBlob]
  });
```

Now here's the email2.html (shortened a bit, just so you guys have a clue what's going on)

```html
<p style="line-height: 160%; font-size: 14px;"><b>Time and date:</b> <?!= M ?>, <?!= G ?></p>
<p style="line-height: 160%; font-size: 14px;"><b>Maximum time and date </b> <?!= N ?></p>
```

So as you can see, using appropriate placeholders succesfully puts the contents of columnid into the email's body, that works 100% correct.

Now, the trouble begins with attachment.html which no matter what I do doesn't recognize and can't load the values from spreadsheet, leaving me with the placeholders in plaintext.

Comment: Please focus question and provide [mcve]  for just that focused question.  I'm not interested in debugging your entire script